# Unable to get fftData while recording specific node

Tags: audiokit

I've got a problem: I use fftData to draw some custom audio visualiser and now I need to add recording function to my project. But I've got following exception when recorder should fire: "VAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAEGraphNode.mm:804:CreateRecordingTap: (nullptr == Tap())]". 
If I remove tap from node before recorded.record() has been called, I lose fftData to draw visualiser. 
How can I combine recording and fftData at the same time?

Thanks, U.

**Edit:**

I tried the following code:

```html
var booster = AKBooster(AudioKit.output)
AudioKit.start()
booster.start()
var fft = AKFFTTap(booster)
var recorder = AKNodeRecorder(AudioKit.output)
```

But in this case I can record output to file but cannot get fftData and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be effectively tapping the same node twice, which is not allowed.  Instead, send the node's output into another node, say an AKBooster with gain set to one or an AKMixer with a single output.  Now you'll have a second node with the exact same data that can be tapped or recorded.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I managed to record output without losing fftData.